# For each IP, there is only one MAC address? 

Tags: ip, protocols

I read a book about IP & MAC addresses.

As I understand, we use ARP in order to find the MAC address of the PC.

My question is if there is only one MAC address for each IP's address? And if so, why do we need the IP address? Why we can't easily go to the MAC address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should only be one MAC address per IP address but the MAC address never leaves the subnet and the MAC address has nothing to do with routing outside the subnet. You can't say anything about where a packet should go from outside the subnet given only MAC address. Think of it like a person's name. Even if it were unique it wouldn't help you find them. You need to look up the street address (ARP) and use a map (routing table) to figure out how to get there. Then once you get to the right house (subnet) you just dump all the mail on the counter and let everyone pick up the mail with their name (MAC address) on it.

Comment: There *should be* only one MAC address per IP address, the converse  is certainly wrong

Comment: Of course you are right. I don't know why I wrote it backwards. You are right about the "should" as well.